# Java Array of Arrays length

Tags: java

```
private class TrieNode<T>{
    private data;
    private TrieNode[] children;
    public TrieNode(){
       data = null;
       children = new TrieNode[26];
    }
    public int getSize(){
       int length = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
           if(children[i]!=null){
               length += children[i].getSize()+1;
            }
        }
     return length;
    }


}
```

Hey can someone please tell me why the getSize method is always giving me one less than it is supposed to?

Comment: Can you give a complete example program? I don't think the getSize method *always* gives one less the right size

Comment: you should simply put some check-points and debug your code to find the problem

Comment: If you think it's one less than it should be, why not add one to the result?

Answer (score 1):

When writing a recursive algorithm, you need a base case...
In this case the base case is when your Trie has no children.
Here we would expect a length of 1.

The recursive case is held inside your for loop (An internal node). You should not be adding one for each iteration of the loop, this is handled by the base case. Instead you should just be adding the size of each child.

Try the following code...

```java
public int getSize() {
    int length = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++ ) {
       if(children[i]!=null) {
          length += children[i].getSize();
       }
    }

    return length;
}
```

Comment: I assume your answer is correct if and only if `getSize` should return all nodes of DS. If it's intended to return only size of a root node's children, then it's wrong.

Comment: If we just want how many children the Trie has... `length` should start as 0.

Comment: @HMD Overall what the algorithm is or is not supposed to do was never specified. So, we both could be wrong or right. I just assumed he wanted how many nodes were in the entire tree.